# MySQL Copy Records in Many to Many Join

Tags: php, mysql, sql, stored-procedures, many-to-many

I have a many-to-many join in MySQL linking Roles to Tasks (Three tables: roles, tasks & roles_tasks). Each Role and Task belongs to a Project.

```
Roles Table
id | project_id | role
---|------------|-------------
1  | 1          | Supervisor
2  | 1          | Manager

Tasks Table
id | project_id | task
---|------------|-------------
1  | 1          | Do this
2  | 1          | Do that

role_task Table
role_id | task_id
-----------------
1       | 1
1       | 2
2       | 1
```

I'm looking for a pure SQL way to copy the roles, tasks and their associated many-to-many join from one project to a different project. What I'd like to finish up with is this:

```
Roles Table
id | project_id | role
---|------------|-------------
1  | 1          | Supervisor
2  | 1          | Manager
3  | 2          | Supervisor
4  | 2          | Manager

Tasks Table
id | project_id | task
---|------------|-------------
1  | 1          | Do this
2  | 1          | Do that
3  | 2          | Do this
4  | 2          | Do that

role_task Table
role_id | task_id
--------|--------
1       | 1
1       | 2
2       | 1
3       | 3
3       | 4
4       | 3
```

I can copy/duplicate the data in the Roles table and Tasks table without a problem. However, how do I copy the role_task table with the new Roles id's and Tasks id's? I can do it in PHP with loops and grabbing the inserted id, but would prefer a pure SQL solution. Thanks

Comment: Do you have 3 tables, i.e. Roles, Tasks and role_task?

Comment: I don't understand what is the exact result you expect from the database.

Answer (score 1):

The only sensible way I was able to do this was to add a field to the Roles and Tasks table that saved the id of the original record. The role_task table remains unchanged but my other two tables now look like this:

```
roles table
id | project_id | original_id | role
---|------------|-------------|-----
1  | 1          | 0           | Supervisor
2  | 1          | 0           | Manager

tasks table
id | project_id | original_id | task
---|------------|-------------|-----
1  | 1          | 0           | Do this
2  | 1          | 0           | Do that
```

So, the SQL to duplicate the roles and the tasks to a project_id of 3 is:

```
INSERT roles
SELECT NULL, 3, id, role FROM Roles WHERE project_id = 1

INSERT tasks
SELECT NULL, 3, id, task FROM Tasks WHERE project_id = 1
```

Then, to duplicate the many-to-many table:

```
INSERT role_task
SELECT r.id, t.id
FROM role_task AS rt
LEFT JOIN roles AS r ON rt.role_id = r.original_id
LEFT JOIN tasks AS t ON rt.task_id = t.original_id
WHERE  r.project_id = 3
AND    t.project_id = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Providing the task and roles tables are auto incrementing you may be able to do something like the following…

Note I have used 3 as project_id but this can be a lookup from another table within the database..

```
INSERT INTO tasks (project_id, task) SELECT DISTINCT 3 ,`task` FROM `tasks`;

INSERT INTO roles (project_id, role) SELECT DISTINCT 3,`role` FROM `roles`;

INSERT INTO role_tasks (task_id, role_id) SELECT tasks.id AS task_id, roles.id AS role_id FROM `tasks` CROSS JOIN `roles`  WHERE tasks.project_id=3 AND roles.project_id=3
```

Comment: The data in the role_task table can't be constructed from a cross join - it's not a everything-to-everything relationship. In my example 'Manager' (id=2) is only assigned the task 'Do this' (id=1), not the task 'Do that' (id=2).